# SWRevealViewController

Tags: swift, view, swift3

ребят может у кого была такая проблема не вызывается меню при нажатии на кнопку вот код

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 240
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        refresh.tintColor = UIColor.red
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.populate), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refresh)


        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
        menubtn.target = self.revealViewController()
        menubtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        //self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

ошибки невыдает просто невыводит меню а при добавлении этой строчки

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

выводит вот такую ошибку

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

понятное дело что можно написать вот так

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

но тогда просто ничего неработает так как `self.revealViewController() = nil`

не могу понять в чем дело создал пробный проект все работает а в моем нет в чем может быть проблема? Любые вариант пожалуйста или предложение как по другому можно реализовать меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я не могу сделать так чтобы после view controller запускался main view так как loading view проходит проверка логина и пароля и поэтому когда я использую

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

у меня выдает ошибку так как `self.revealViewController() = nil` и как это исправить вообще немогу понять

Comment: Покажите где Вы и как инициализируете revealViewController

Comment: @Vitali Eller инициализирую его в header вот так . '#import "SWRevealViewController.h"'

Comment: Так Вы ипмортируете нужную библиотеку, а как создаете?

Comment: @Vitali Eller  что создаю я непонял вашего вопроса((

Comment: вот от этого должно работать . 'menubtn.target = self.revealViewController()
        menubtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        //self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно после логина  запускать swrevealcontroller потом создать еще 1 navigation и только потом navigation соединить c mainviewcontroller

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25jzqZKTx-E